# How do I loop through async function in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Here is a sample code which am using for selenium WebDriver JS axe integration to test my website for accessibility -

```
var AxeBuilder = require('axe-webdriverjs');
var WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new WebDriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('firefox')
  .build();

driver
  .get('https://dequeuniversity.com/demo/mars/')
  .then(function() {
    AxeBuilder(driver).analyze(function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error somehow
      }
      console.log(results);
    });
  });
```

There is one URL that is being parsed here. Can someone help me with how I can parse multiple urls? I would want the print the results of all the urls being given as input to driver.get(). Any help would be appreciated !

Reference - https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-webdriverjs

Comment: `await` each `Promise` or use `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 1):

So I'll format the @CertainPerformance's comment as an answer.

The simplest approach is using the modern `async/await` syntax:

```
for (const url of [url1, url2, url3]) {
    await driver
      .get(url)
      .then(async function() {
        await AxeBuilder(driver).analyze(function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            // Handle error somehow
          }
          console.log(results);
        });
      });
}
```

Do not forget to replace `url1, url2, url3` with your urls.

P.S. as @jfriend00 stated (in comments below), we don't know if `AxeBuilder` function is actually returns a promise or not. So the `await` before it (and `async`) may be unnecessary in the latter case.

Comment: This won't wait for `AxeBuilder().analyze()` to finish before going onto the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 Missed that, fixed!

Comment: I don't know this library, but its unlikely that .analyze() returns a promise and takes a callback.  If it doesn't return a promise, await won't do anything useful.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yep, added a postscriptum.

Comment: You still don't show a solution that would actually wait for all async things to be done before iterating the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 I might be missing something. What are those things?

Comment: I already said it in my first comment here.  Hint, you need to "promisify" `.analyze()`.

Answer (score 1):

the above solution will work, but it will be serialized i.e. you will get the result of the `driver.get` promise and then `analyze` the result of one url before moving to the next. maybe you could use `promise.all` to do it all in parallel. Something on the lines of

```
function executeGetPromises() {
    var getPromises = [];
    var drivers = [];
    for (const url of [url1, url2, url3]) {
        var driver = new WebDriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
        getPromises.push(driver.get(url));
        drivers.push(driver);
    }

    var analysePromises = [];
    int index = 0;
    Promise.all(getPromises.map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
        .then(results => {
            for (int i=0; i< results.length; i++) {
                var result = results[i];
                if (!(result instanceof Error)) {
                    analysePromises.push(AxeBuilder(drivers[i]).analyze);
                }
            }
        executeAnalysePromises(analysePromises);
    });
}

function executeAnalysePromises (analysePromises) {
    Promise.all(analysePromises.map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
    .then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
            if (!(result instanceof Error)) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

here we are keeping a track of all the `drivers`, and all the `driver.get` promises are run in parallel and once all the `getPromises` return (either resolved/rejected), the `analysePromises` get executed in parallel.

EDIT: A more simpler approach using async functions. The above is a bit complicated, you can achieve the same using async functions

```
async function executeTask (driver, url) {
    try{
        await driver.get(url);
        let result = await AxeBuilder(driver).analyze();
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    } 
    catch(err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}

function iterateThroughUrls(urls) {
    urls.forEach(url => {
        var driver = new WebDriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
        executeTask(driver, url).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            //handle errors
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Mrinal firstly thanks ! Quick question, What if I do not want this to run in parallel and serialize this exact code? It runs flawlessly the only issue is if am giving it a large number of urls, it crashes. Kindly help !

Answer (score 1):

Use Promise.all and map a url array.

```
const urlArray = [url1,url2,url3,...];
const finalResult = await Promise.all(urlArray.map(async url=>{
   return await driver.get(url);
}))
```

you will get all the result in the array `finalResult`.